# Can't see shared movie on facebook wall

Tags: video, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to share this video on facebook and i dont see the thumbnail and play button in my wall.
i think that all of the og metatags are here and it used to work. can anyone spot the problem?

Thanks,

http://www.kaltura.com/index.php/extwidget/openGraph/wid/0_8km066su#.UThlE42n0M8.facebook

Comment: Fix the warnings: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kaltura.com%2Findex.php%2Fextwidget%2FopenGraph%2Fwid%2F0_8km066su%23.UThlE42n0M8.facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

1. never leave the description empty.
2. add `og:url` meta property.

> > meta property="og:url" content="http://www.kaltura.com/index.php/extwidget/openGraph/wid/0_8km066su#.UThlE42n0M8.facebook"

1. put the secure URLs directly in the `og:image` and `og:video` meta properties and remove the `og:video:secure_url` and `og:image:secure_url` meta properties.

> > meta property="og:video" content="https://www.kaltura.com/kwidget/wid/0_8km066su/entry_id/1_d5o9twuk/ui_conf/8700151
> >
> > meta property="og:image" content="https://cdnbakmi.kaltura.com/p/1281471/sp/128147100/thumbnail/entry_id/1_d5o9twuk/version/100001"

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the image size -- looks like facebook need minmum 200x200 thumbnail - thanks @alexi